# nanoFramework - I2C device is not responding

Tags: nanoframework

New to nanoframework here, but following some [sample code](https://www.hackster.io/nanoframework/ht16k33-with-nanoframework-67e86a) I'm unable to get a 7-segment display working with my ESP32 MCU.

I'm on VS 2019. Using the latest nanoframework extension (2019.5.0.14). My project is very simple, using these packages:

```
<package id="nanoFramework.CoreLibrary" version="1.10.1-preview.11" targetFramework="netnanoframework10" />
<package id="nanoFramework.Runtime.Events" version="1.9.0-preview.14" targetFramework="netnanoframework10" />
<package id="nanoFramework.Windows.Devices.I2c" version="1.4.1-preview.29" targetFramework="netnanoframework10" />
```

I've even tried simplifying the code down to just this:

```
I2cDevice _display = I2cDevice.FromId("I2C1", new I2cConnectionSettings(0x70) { BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.FastMode });
_display.Write(new byte[] { 0x21 });
```

What I've tried:

- Verifying that `0x70` is the correct I2C bus address (yes it is)
- Using the same 7-segment display and MCU with sample project in Arudino IDE (works fine)
- Step debugging in VS to see if any errors are thrown (nothing errors out)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, what resolved the issue for me was reassigning other GPIO pins (14 and 15) to SDA/SCL with:

```
Configuration.SetPinFunction(14, DeviceFunction.I2C1_DATA);
Configuration.SetPinFunction(15, DeviceFunction.I2C1_CLOCK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering this in our [Discord server](https://discord.com/channels/478725473862549535/709495457222492160/820055407334522881).